# Where to initialize in Swift?

Tags: swift, initialization

I have a very general question about the Initialization in Swift.
Unlike in Objective C it's now possible to call the init() directly at the declaration outside of my functions:
e.g.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let myView: UIView = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myView.frame = getFrame()
        myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.view.addSubview(myView)

    }

    func getFrame() -> CGRect {
        return CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
    }
}
```

In Objective C I would have done the initialization in my function.

But what if I want to call an Initializer with parameters which are not set yet?
e.g. 
I want to init with a frame which is being calculated in a func()

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //THIS IS NOT WOKRING
    let myView: UIView = UIView(frame: getFrame())

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.view.addSubview(myView)

    }

    func getFrame() -> CGRect {
        return CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
    }
}
```

I don't wanna do my initializations at two different places in the Code. Is there any general pattern for the initializations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So your options for initialisation in swift are numerous. With your current example you cannot use the method `getFrame()` yet because you do not yet have a reference to `self` as the `ViewController` has not get been initialised. Instead you could use:

```
let myView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
```

As this does not require the reference to self. Alternatively you could `lazy` instantiation which will get run after `self` is available (this can only be used with `var` not `let`:

```
lazy var myView: UIView = {
    return UIView(frame:self.getFrame())
}()
```

To answer your question, when using UIKit class where you often don't have control over their instantiation you can keep doing it the same was as you were in objective c and use [implicitly unwrapped](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/implicitly-unwrapped-optional-type) optionals (to prevent you having to use a `!` or `?` every time you instantiate a variable, e.g.:

```
var myView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad();

    myView = UIView(frame:getFrame())
}
```

This however does not work with `let` constants, as they need to be assigned either immediately or in the constructor of the object. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for that great answer! 
How would you do it?

Comment: There is no hard and fast rule as it really depends on the type of class. In saying that I normally declare all constants in line (i.e. `let`), use `lazy var` for values with defaults and then initialise all variables as early on in the lifecycle of the class as possible. So in model classes (e.g. `User` or `Person`) in the init and in the `viewDidLoad` of of a `UIViewController`.